# .viminfo owned by root?

Tags: root, vim, vi

The .viminfo file in my home directory is owned by root. Could anyone please explain how that could have happened without me asking it?

```
$ ls -la | grep .viminfo
-rw-------  1 root    root       4175 Nov  3 19:11 .viminfo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it was created while using "sudo vim" to edit some file on the system.

Comment: `sudo -s` or `-u` retain the shell environment, i.e. the users home directory when using `sudo` thus vim thinks it is supposed to be so.

Comment: After digging a bit I found that .viminfo is created when you run vim for the first time. I ran 'sudo vim' to edit  /etc/apt/sources.list file. Since 'sudo' keeps $HOME variable, .viminfo was created in my home directory with root as the owner.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you run vim after sudo -s

You can chown it back to your id:group anyway, does't hurt;-)

Comment: Isn't this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It might have happened that `~/.viminfo` was created with those permissions when vim was used with root privileges, i.e. `sudo vim`.
You can change it back to being owned by you user and group like this:

```
sudo chown $(id -nu):$(id -ng) ~/.viminfo
```

[The place where I found the above command](https://blog.robertelder.org/vim-forgets-copy-buffer-on-reopen/) also has a really good explanation of the use of `.viminfo` and the (negative) effects of it being owned by root.

Over on [this StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134500/vim-error-e138-cant-write-viminfo-file-home-viminfo) there is [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134531/264584) with some good tips on how to edit files with root privileges in a way that avoids this issue.